# how to find out the file format for .eml file to be used for accept attribute in input type="file"?

Tags: html, file-extension

I am using a file input html element for file upload.

```
<input type="file" name="data[File][0][attachment]" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/pdf"style="display:inline;width:70%% !important;" class="file-upload" />
```

I know that for:

- pdf is `application/pdf`
- MS word is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

I need to add .eml into the `accept` attribute as well

How do I find out for .eml file type?

I tried `application/eml` it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `.eml` files have no mime type. It's not listed here http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml.

But since the `accept` attribute accept both mime types and file extensions, you can add `.eml` to it's value. Try this

```html
<input type="file" name="data[File][0][attachment]" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/pdf,.eml"style="display:inline;width:70%% !important;" class="file-upload" />
```